# Constant, random and inexplicable (to me, anyway) EXC BAD ACCESS in Objective C app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, glkit

I have Automatic Reference Counting and Zombies enabled...

I keep getting EXC BAD ACCESS to different points in the code, most of the time with no further information coming from zombies.

The objective is to draw a rectangle to the screen with a texture on it that is loaded from an image. It does actually work! But often it is corrupted (the image and the vectors) and then often I just get the exc bad access warning.

I have this sort of structure...

App Delegate Class Declaration:

```
GWBackgroundScene* background;
EAGLContext *context;
GLKView *view;
GLKViewController *controller;
UIWindow *window;
```

and then window is made into a property and synthesized.

The did Finish Launching With Options:

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

view = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] context:context];
view.delegate = self;

controller = [[GLKViewController alloc] init];
[controller shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.view = view;

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = controller;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

background = [[GWBackgroundScene alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC_0059.jpg"]];
```

The AppDelegate acts as an OpenGL delegate and OpenGL calls a function called 'render' in the class which then calls [background render];

My GWBackgroundScene class:

```
@interface GWBackgroundScene : NSObject
{
    GLKTextureInfo *texture;
    NSMutableData* vertexData;
    NSMutableData* textureCoordinateData;
}  
@property(readonly) GLKVector2 *vertices;
@property(readonly) GLKVector2 *textureCoordinates;
-(void) render;
-(id) initWithImage: (UIImage*)image;
```

Initialises with:

```
self = [super init];

if(self != nil)
{
  texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber   numberWithBool:YES]                                                                                        forKey:GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft]  error:&error];

    vertexData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:4];
    textureCoordinateData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:4];

    self.vertices[0] = GLKVector2Make(-2.0,3.0);     
    ...

    self.textureCoordinates[0] = GLKVector2Make(0,0);
    ...
}

return self;
```

and has these two functions for dealing with the vector and texture information

```
- (GLKVector2 *)vertices {
  return [vertexData mutableBytes];
}
- (GLKVector2 *)textureCoordinates {
return [textureCoordinateData mutableBytes];
}
```

and then the render function (which is called by OpenGL via its delegate (the App delegate) uses:

1. texture:

   ```
   GLKBaseEffect *effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
   effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
   effect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
   effect.texture2d0.name = texture.name;
   ```
2. self.vertices:

   ```
   glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, self.vertices);
   ```
3. self.textureCordinates

   ```
   glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, self.textureCoordinates);
   ```

What are the obvious memory issues with what im doing?

Thanks very much

Comment: What does your backtrace say?

Comment: @CarlNorum -- You don't usually get a backtrace with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @Hot Licks, you should be able to get a backtrace at *any* time, so I'm pretty sure you can.

Comment: If you're getting this in the ARC environment, and it's this pervasive, odds are pretty good that you've got some misunderstanding about how something works, either in ARC or generally.  But, anyway, to nail down the problem you probably have to resort to the age-old technique of inserting NSLogs in the code and narrowing in on a few scenarios where it crashes, or where the data goes bad.  It's simple hard, frustrating work.

Comment: @CarlNorum -- Yep, you *should*.  But you don't.

Comment: Before giving up on the tools, have you tried the Product>Analyze command?

Comment: yeah i think misunderstanding is probably the reason, just trying to figure out how to proceed really!

Comment: This is the back trace:#0  0x0359c7d0 in llvm::TypeMap<llvm::FunctionValType, llvm::FunctionType>::RefineAbstractType ()
#1  0x03594c25 in llvm::FunctionType::refineAbstractType ()
.......
#13 0x94628ed9 in _pthread_start ()
........
#14 0x9462c6de in thread_start ()

Comment: The product analyse can't find any issues

Comment: @user1068223 Why are you calling shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:? This isn't a method you should call. You should implement it if you want to have custom orientation support, but not call it! (Calling it shouldn't cause any problems, it will just call the default version in UIViewController and throw away the result. But calling it will do nothing.)

Comment: @occulus yeah thats a line i left in there from a while ago.

Comment: "self.vertices[3] = GLKVector2Make(-2.0,3.0);"
Often seems to have the degger stop on it when the BAD ACCESS is called - not always, but sometimes. THe way im writing/access this - is that going to lead to memory problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an NSMutableData object with size 4 bytes, but the data type GLKVector2 is larger than 1 byte. If you're expecting to store a few objects in there you should do

```
vertexData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:4 * sizeof(GLKVector2)];
```

And similarly for textureCoordinateData.

Comment: I cant believe how unhelpful those bad access warnings are! I couldnt even find a decent tutorial on how to debug them. I suppose the way you create them is also relevant though; very poor programming like me might throw them up more often!

Comment: Well, if you're using C arrays, you start to get pretty 'close to the metal', and debugging becomes a pain. EXC_BAD_ACCESS just means the program tried to access some memory that it shouldn't have, going off the end of an array is a pretty classic cause.